# Why do i get "The partial header could not be found" error when I set up my hbs files this way?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am getting this error "Error: C:\Users\Don-Alex Antoine\Desktop\Daily-Scripture\templates\views\home.hbs: The partial headers could not be found" when I run my node app.
This is the code inside my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const body = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.listen(process.env.PORT|| 3000,()=>{
    console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
});

//Defined path for express config

const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views');
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials');

app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath));

app.set('views', viewsPath);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath);

app.use(body.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{

    res.render('home');
});
```

Everything works perfectly until I change my header.hbs into this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta>
        <title>Daily-Scripture</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
```

my home.hbs file into this:

```
{{>headers}}

    <h1>PlEASE WORK!!</h1>

{{>footer}}
```

and my footer.hbs file into this

```
<footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when I add everything into the home.hbs file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Daily-Scripture</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>PLEASE WORK</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything works perfectly. I wanted to have a separate hbs file that contains the necessary headers such as the title, and the link to the stylesheet and use that in other hbs files if that's even possible. If you guys know what I'm doing wrong here I would appreciate the help.

Comment: If the partial's file name is "header.hbs", then the partial's name will be "header", not "headers" and will need to be referenced as `{{>header}}`.

Comment: I did but it's still not working

Comment: after some testing, I found out that it doesn't work when I try to use headers. I think there might be something wrong with the way I have it setup in the app.js file

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: It might be a good idea to post your solution in case it could help someone else in the future.

Comment: I basically deleted and wrote it over again and somehow it worked.